# C - Array in two for-loops

Tags: c, arrays

Why does this code print as it does? I am trying to understand why this code with arrays prints as it does, but I am not quite sure. Can anyone try to help me understand? Thanks!

```
int main (void)
{
  int numbers[10] = {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  int i, j;

  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
      numbers[j] += numbers[i];
    }
  }

  for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
  {
    printf ("%d ", numbers[j]);
    printf ("\n");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show us output. What can't you understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one loop that will iterate trough array and modify each element as a sum of all others. Only catch is that sum changes as `j` changes.

- On start array is: `1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`
- After first iteration: `1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0` when `j = 0`
- After second iteration: `1,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0`  when `j = 1`
- After third iteration: `1, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0` when `j = 2`
  etc.

Please read more about [for](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_for_loop.htm) loops.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but how is the next 4 then - when j = 3?

Comment: Because second loop iterates trough array and when `j = 3` you will change value of `array[3]`, you will change it with second loop: `array[0] + array[1] + ...` and so it will sum you `1 + 1 + 2` which is 4.

Comment: In first iteration: `array[3] = array[3] + array[0]`, and in next iteration of second for loop `array[3] = array[3] + array[1]` etc.

Comment: Thank you! This was helpful :)